# How 4 primary coil induces voltage in one secondary coil

Tags: transformer

[image]

How 4 coils induces voltage in secondary coil. And how much voltage and current will induces in secondary coil.

All 4 coils are connected parallel, 20 turns in each coil,200 turns in secondary coil ,voltage of 100V and coils are made of copper

Comment: Depends how you connect them. They are supplied as separate windings to you can connect them different ways for different purposes. You'll need to know the turns ratios to predict the voltages, and what it's connected to, to know the currents. The note suggests one way to connect them, suitable for a low primary voltage and high primary current.

Comment: "*And how much voltage and current will induces in secondary coil.*" The primary will induce **voltage** in the secondary. The load will determine the current.

Answer (score 1):

> Primary windings to be connected in parallel on PC board

That's telling you they all have the same number of turns.

When connected in parallel, they will behave, to first order, as a single primary with copper cross-section equal to the sum of all the windings.

There are several reasons why a primary might be split like this. One is that the required area of copper wire would be too stiff to physically wind in a single conductor, so it's split into four parallel windings of thinner wire. Another is that the transformer may be intended for flexible operation where the windings could also be connected in series to increase the voltage while reducing the current. Another is that the primary is split both 'under' and 'over' the secondary, to improve leakage inductance.

There will be some second order effects of a split primary, we could expect the leakage inductance, or the self capacitance and hence self resonant frequency, to be slightly affected. However, the first order transformer specifications of turns ratio, power handling, resistive losses, primary inductance, will be as if there was a single thick wire primary winding.

Comment: What is difference between using four 20 turns coil as primary and a 80 turns coil as primary.

Comment: Do you understand basic transformer turns ratio theory?

Comment: If connected in parallel like the diagram in the OP says, then no different to having 20 turns of thick wire. If connected in series, as they could be, then no different to having 80 turns of thin wire. When series connected, the terminals would be supplying 4x the voltage at one quarter of the current, for the same magnetic core and secondary conditions, compared to the parallel connection. Do you understand the difference between series and parallel?